# Cosa significa "per morti" in questo brano del Decameron?

Tags: meaning

Nell'esordio della prima novella della Nona giornata del *Decameron*, la narratrice, Filomena, dice queste parole (grassetto mio):

> Molte volte s'è, o vezzose donne, ne' nostri ragionamenti mostrato quante e quali sieno le forze d'amore; né però credo che pienamente se ne sia detto né sarebbe ancora, se di qui a uno anno d'altro che di ciò non parlassimo: e per ciò che esso non solamente a varii dubbii di dover morire gli amanti conduce ma quegli ancora a entrare nelle case de' morti **per morti** tira, m'agrada di ciò raccontarvi, oltre a quelle che dette sono, una novella nella quale non solamente la potenzia d'amore comprenderete, ma il senno da una valorosa donna usato a torsi da dosso due, che contro al suo piacere l'amavan, cognoscerete.

Non sono sicura del significato dell'espressione "per morti" in questa frase. Capisco che Filomena sta dicendo che "le forze d'amore" a volte spingono gli amanti a entrare nelle case dei morti, cioè, nelle loro sepolture, ma non so quale sia il ruolo della precisazione "per morti". Vorrebbe dire che fanno questo come se loro stessi fossero morti? Ho leto le note di Amedeo Quondam all'edizione BUR e quelle di Vittore Branca all'edizione Einaudi del *Decameron*, ma non spiegano nulla riguardo a questa locuzione.

Comment: A orecchio, direi che significhi semplicemente che entrano nelle sepolture da morti, in quanto morti. Sembrerebbe confermarlo, ma non in modo chiarissimo, l'edizione che ho sotto mano (a c. di Bruno Maier, Zanichelli 1967) che a “per” dà in nota “come”.

Comment: @DaG:   Ah, allora il significato sarebbe che a volte questi amanti finiscono effettivamente per morire. Ha senso.

Comment: @DaG:  Ho appena scoperto che Boccaccio usa un'altra volta questa stessa espressione nel titolo della quarta novella della Decima giornata: «Messer Gentil de' Carisendi, venuto da Modona, trae della sepoltura una donna amata da lui, sepellita **per morta**; [...]». In questo caso è chiaro dalla vicenda narrata nella novella che "per morta" significa "ritenuta morta, come se fosse morta".

Comment: Curiosamente, però, James McMullen Rigg traduce l'espressione nella [prima novella della Nona giornata](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14038/cosa-significa-per-morti-in-questo-brano-del-decameron) come "in quest of the dead", invece nella [quarta novella della Decima giornata](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Italian_Studies/dweb/texts/DecShowText.php?myID=nov1004&lang=eng) la traduzione è "for dead".